# Declaration or Statement Expected in javascript in switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a "declaration or statement expected" error anyone knows why? This code basically fetches data from the database and used to feed it to my chatbot agent.
I just started coding a bot, and I'm having a problem with coding with API. I don't know if the entire code is wrong I'm confused with it. I have an error in the default statement. How do I fix the problem?
I'm using Visual Studio Code to code, and Node.js.Thanks in advance

```
                switch (displayName) {
                    case "list-available-meals":
                        const data = collection.find({});
                        const meals = [{
                            text: {
                                text: [
                                    `We currently have the following 20 meals on our menu list. Which would you like to request for?`,
                                ],
                            },
                        }, ];
                        result.push(
                            data.forEach((item) => {
                                const {
                                    name,
                                    description,
                                    price,
                                    availableUnits,
                                    image_uri,
                                } = item;
                                const card = {
                                    card: {
                                        title: `${name} at $${price}`,
                                        subtitle: description,
                                        imageUri: image_uri,
                                    },
                                };
                                meals.push(card);
                            })
                        );
                        return Promise.all(result)
                            .then((_) => {
                                const response = {
                                    fulfillmentMessages: meals,
                                };
                                res.status(200).json(response);
                            })
                            .catch((e) => res.status(400).send({ error: e }));

                    case "request-meal":
                        const { food } = req.body.queryResult.parameters;

                        collection.findOne({ name: food }, (err, data) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    res.status(400).send({ error: err });
                                }
                                const { name, price, description, image_uri } = data;
                                const singleCard = [{
                                        text: {
                                            text: [`The ${name} is currently priced at $${price}.`],
                                        },
                                    },
                                    {
                                        card: {
                                            title: `${name} at $${price}`,
                                            subtitle: description,
                                            imageUri: image_uri,
                                            buttons: [{
                                                text: "Pay For Meal",
                                                postback: "htts://google.com",
                                            }, ],
                                        },
                                    },
                                ];
                                res.status(200).json(singleCard);

                                default:
                                break;

                            }
```

Comment: You can't just add a `break;` or `return ...` where ever  you want. Please make this a [mcve].

Comment: @Andreas what should I do?

Comment: `const data = collection.find({})` will never return anything. Objects are compared by identity; two empty objects are never equal to each other.

Comment: @Pointy  const collection = client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME).collection("Meals"); I used this before it so it should work fine right? I'm getting error in switch statement, I'm guessing it's a syntax error

Comment: As already said. Please transform this into a [mcve] (And your `switch` cases are way too complicated. Extract the "cases" into separate functions and call these instead of all that "inline" code) or otherwise we can only guess what the actual problem might be.